# Use imported script inside development build of Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, vuejs3, jspdf

I'm currently building an application and, and I applied vue 3 only in one page via script.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
```

I'm trying to use the imported module (jsPdf) via a script, and it is not working.

```
methods: {
  generateReport() {
    let pdfName = 'test'; 
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Hello World", 10, 10);
    doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
  }
}
```

This is the error when I'm trying to do the method above:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
```

Is it possible to use the module imported using script in the development build of Vue? or is there any other way to generate pdf without importing scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet

```js
const { jsPDF } = jspdf
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: "#demo",
  methods: {
    generateReport() {
      let pdfName = 'test'; 
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text("Hello World", 10, 10);
      doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
      console.log(doc)
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="generateReport">pdf</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If `jsPDF is not defined`, so how `const { jsPDF } = jspdf` can work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the library in the .vue file you are trying to use it in?
`import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";`